# Display ShortTime format in Access to VB in 24 hours format

Tags: vb.net, datetime, ms-access, maskedtextbox

in Microsoft Access the ShortTime format is display as per below picture.

Access in Short Time format:

[image]

I have tried several ways to make sure that the ShortTime in Access will be displayed in MaskedTextBox in 24 hours format. For example like:

> TStart = 01:26
>
> TEnd = 02:30

And after several times, finally I'm able to displayed it in 24 hours format with below coding:

```
If DBNull.Value.Equals(ds2.Tables("OTTimeTable").Rows(i).Item("TStart")) Then
    tstat_tb.Text = "  :"
Else
    tstat_tb.Text = Format(ds2.Tables("OTTimeTable").Rows(i).Item("TStart"), "HH:mm")
End If

If DBNull.Value.Equals(ds2.Tables("OTTimeTable").Rows(i).Item("TEnd")) Then
    tend_tb.Text = "  :"
Else
    tend_tb.Text = Format(ds2.Tables("OTTimeTable").Rows(i).Item("TEnd"), "HH:mm")
End If
```

Windows Form in 24 hours format:

[image: Windows Form in 24 hours format]

Does the coding need some more improvement or is there any ways to make it more better?

Comment: That's not what this site is for.  If you code does what it's supposed to then it's working so there's no reason to ask a question here.

Comment: You pretty much have the shortest code possible to do what you require. What could you possibly want to improve? -- Also, questions like this should rather be asked on [**Code Review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @VisualVincent thank you. I was searching for a ways to ask such question but I couldn't find it in here. Will ask this question on Code Review instead. Thanks

Comment: I still don't see why you need to ask a question about it... There's really nothing to improve, like I said. What answer do you expect to get?

Comment: @VisualVincent I thought that there will be another ways to make it better but if you said that this is okay then its fine with me :)